# Pyephem sublat and sublong equivalent for the Moon?

Tags: the-moon

Just wondering, does anyone know a good way to calculate latitude and longitude of the moon relative to the earth with PyEphem?
I've kinda hit a wall trying to figure it out...

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use equatorial coordinates given in [Right Ascension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_ascension) for longitude and [Declination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declination) for latitude as projected on celestial sphere. So you would do something along the lines of:

```
import ephem
m = ephem.Moon('2003/08/27', epoch=ephem.J2000)
print('%s %s' % (m.a_ra, m.a_dec))
```

This is explained in more detail in [PyEphem Coordinate Transformations](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/coordinates.html). Note that `J2000` is already an assumed epoch and you can simply provide the time since epoch to replace `'2003/08/27'` in the example and omit the second parameter. Equatorial coordinate system is also already assumed when printing out RA/Dec. And if you want to transform RA/Lon and Dec/Lat to XYZ coordinates for a location on Earth's celestial sphere using Python, you'll continue with something like:

```
import math

x = math.cos(m.dec) * math.cos(m.ra)
y = math.cos(m.dec) * math.sin(m.ra)
z = math.sin(m.dec)
```

Refer to the second part of [Brandon Rhodes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963439/1953464) to [Getting J2000 XYZ coordinates for a location on earth in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11957633/1953464) for more info on the latter part.